# Get Array from JSON in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have one problem. Anyone help me out. I am new to React so I am not able to debug it.

The problem is

When I print `this.props.colors` i.e.

```js
console.log(this.props.colors)
```

I got below result.

```
{"colors": [["Red", true], ["Blue", false], ["Green", true], ["Black", true], ["White", false]]}
```

But I want it below form

```
0: (2) ["Red", true]
1: (2) ["Blue", false]
2: (2) ["Green", true]
3: (2) ["Black", true]
4: (2) ["White", false]
```

How can I get this? Anyone help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Like this `this.props.colors.colors`?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Comment: I tried that too. But it prints `undefined`. I tried it as follows

`console.log(this.props.color.colors)`

prints

`{"colors": [["Red", true], ["Blue", false], ["Green", true], ["Black", true], [White", false]]}`

but 

`console.log(this.props.color.colors ? this.props.color.colors.colors : '1111111' )`

prints

`undefined`

Did I miss something?

Comment: @Rich try Object.assign(). Here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cannon-793fm

Answer (score 3):

If data - `this.props.colors` is :

```
{
  "colors": [
     ["Red", true], 
     ["Blue", false], 
     ["Green", true], 
     ["Black", true], 
     ["White", false]]
}
```

try **`this.props.colors.colors[0]`** or **`this.props.colors['colors'][0]`**

Comment: this.props.colors['colors'][0]

Answer (score 1):

Also you can format colors into more comfortable array.

Use `const colors = Object.values(this.props.colors)` then it will return array like

```
[
 Array(5)
    0: ["Red", true]
    1: ["Blue", false]
    2: ["Green", true]
    3: ["Black", true]
    4: ["White", false]
]
```